# How to define log4j2.properties for Spring XD

Tags: spring, log4j2, spring-xd

I have tried defining the log4j2 properties file via the -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j2.properties however it's being ignored, I also tried -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.properties and again nothing. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Spring XD uses logback, not log4j2; to configure logging, modify the `xd-*-logback.groovy` files in `xd/config`.

There's one for the admin, container, and singlenode.

Comment: And is there a way to change spring xd to use log4j2 instead of logback?

Comment: The common logging API is `slf4j` (some components need `jcl-over-slf4j`) - you should be able to remove the logback jars from `xd/lib` and replace them with the `log4j2 2 slf4j` binding. Also see  the [Spring Boot Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration)

Comment: Once done that, would I reference my log4j2.properties via the -Dlogging.config=log4j2.properties passed to SPRING_XD_OPTS?   Thanks Gary!